# "Recursive" spread operator in JS for objects

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have two objects, `obj1 = {key1: value1, key2: {key2_1: value2_1, key2_2: value2_2}}` is for default values and `obj2 = {key2: {key2_2: new_value2_2}}` is for altered values (these come from config defaults and a parsed config file)

I want to combine these into one object where any value in `obj2` replaces that in `obj1` so long as it's not replacing an object, just a singular value. With the example above this would give `obj1 = {key1: value1, key2: {key2_1: value2_1, key2_2: new_value2_2}}`.

I've tried using the spread operator (`...`) but that ends up replacing the whole of `key2` and essentially removing `key2_1` in this case.

Any help would be very nice thanks

Comment: If you want a mechanism like this to be fully dynamic, I'm not sure there's any alternative but to implement your own recursive variant of `Object.assign()` that does what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could merge all values and check the inner object and merge these separately.

```js
const
    merge = (a, b) => [a, b].reduce((r, o) => Object
        .entries(o)
        .reduce((q, [k, v]) => ({
            ...q,
            [k]: v && typeof v === 'object' ? merge(q[k] || {}, v) : v
        }), r),
    {}),
    obj1 = { key1: 'value1', key2: { key2_1: 'value2_1', key2_2: 'value2_2' } },
    obj2 = { key2: { key2_2: 'new_value2_2' } },
    result = merge(obj1, obj2);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a function that will recursively merge properties of the two objects.

Properties of `obj2` will take priority over `obj1` and child objects will be merged key by key.

```js
let obj1 = {key1: 'value1', key2: {key2_1: 'value2_1', key2_2: 'value2_2'}}
let obj2 = {key2: {key2_2: 'new_value2_2'}}

function merge(obj1, obj2) {
    const result = {};
    const combined = { ...obj1, ...obj2 };
    for(let k in combined) {
        if (combined[k] && (typeof(combined[k]) === 'object')) {
            result[k] = merge(obj1[k], obj2[k]);
        } else { 
            result[k] = obj2 ? obj2[k] || obj1[k] : obj1[k]
        }
    }
    return result;
}

console.log('Merged objects:', merge(obj1, obj2))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Comment: Might want to use `??` instead of `||` in that `else` clause, or even check only for `undefined` and leave `null` alone. Depends on the application, but the `||` will override 0 and "" etc.  (*edit* wait this may be wrong ...) (no I think I'd be more cautious but I've had no coffee yet)

Comment: However this is basically the right answer.

Comment: Good point point, ?? is the more correct operator, thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: on the `result[k] = ` line, it needed changing to `obj2 ? obj2[k] || obj1[k] : obj1[k]`. even with `??` instead of `||` it still throws an error from reading properties of undefined in some cases

Comment: @nxe you could use `?.` to make that a little nicer

Answer (score 0):

In case there is no better way of doing it, you can flatten both objects and use the spread operator on those.

With the examples I gave, flattening the objects would give `flatten(obj1) = {"key1": value1, "key2.key2_1": value2_1, "key2.key2_2": value2_2}` and `flatten(obj2) = {"key2.key2_2": new_value2_2}` (flatten funtion is below from [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/flatten-javascript-objects-into-a-single-depth-object/)). You can then do `{...flatten(obj1), ...flatten(obj2)}` to give what I wanted

---

```js
const flatten = (ob) => {
    let result = {};
    for (const i in ob) {
        if ((typeof ob[i]) === 'object' && !Array.isArray(ob[i])) {
            const temp = flatten(ob[i]);
            for (const j in temp) {
                result[i + '.' + j] = temp[j];
            }
        } else {
            result[i] = ob[i];
        }
    }
    return result;
};
```